# Reading file consist of non-English characters in Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, file-io, encoding, windows-phone-8

I have to read file called tur.txt in Windows Phone Application and write it to textblock. The file consist of Turkish characters. Because of this it is not written on textblock properly. I tried this:

System.IO.StreamReader turfile = new StreamReader(@"Assets/tur.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254"));

But I get an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'windows-1254' is not a supported encoding name.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like windows-1254 is an invalid argument for `Encoding.GetEncoding`.  I would start there.